# Are there any free online resources for learning Tamazight?

Tags: resource-request, self-learning, electronic-resources, online-learning, tamazight

I'd like to learn [Tamazight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Atlas_Tamazight) or any related [Berber language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berber_languages) by self-learning, in a first step. As far as I know they are similar to some extent, therefore I'm not excluding the possibility to use another language.

Therefore I'm looking for *preferably free* resources, preferably *online* which have a focus on:

- building up a vocabulary basis.
- learning at least some helpful sentences for a simple communication.
- an extra plus would be if audio material as a help and support to learn the pronunciation would be available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used Memrise for years to help me build up my vocabulary for various languages. It's great in that any language can have a Memrise course built for it, so it works well for less popular ones such as Tamazight. [Here](http://www.memrise.com/course/101986/basic-tamazight-berber-kabyle/) is a Memrise course for learning Tamazight. I find that getting comfortable with some basic vocab and hearing the sounds of the language are the best first steps into a new language. I'd like to point you to some quality auditory material, but that does seem to be lacking. Maybe someone else will be able to help you out there.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, that can help you :

- MOOC Tarifit berber/Riffian language from the Leiden university :

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbowmAxU24U

- MOOC Riffian language from an amateur :

https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCmnjNnMO2mthw4uLkIeSnEg/playlists